# How to generate a named vector (i.e: "0" = "blue") without hardcoding in R

Tags: r, vector, paste

```
y = as.character(c(0:7))
[1] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"
```

foo is the levels of some vector. 
I have a function that needs a color for each of these levels. An output that I need is :

```
 c("0" = "red", "1" = "pink", "2" = "green")
```

etc.

I want to enter this into a function, where depending on the user's vector y, it will take the levels of the function and map it to some colors.

Here is what I was able to do so far:

```
tmp <- as.factor(c(0:7))
leng <- length(tmp)

colrs <- rainbow(leng)

temp2 <- c(rbind(tmp, colrs))
cat(paste(shQuote(temp2, type="cmd"), collapse=" = "))
```

output:

```
"1" = "#FF0000FF" = "2" = "#FFBF00FF" = "3" = "#80FF00FF" = "4" = "#00FF40FF" = "5" = "#00FFFFFF" = "6" = "#0040FFFF" = "7" = "#8000FFFF" = "8" = "#FF00BFFF"
```

That's not necessarily right..

Comment: `setNames(colrs, tmp)`?

Comment: `names(tmp)<-rainbow(length(tmp))`

Comment: Its a bit harsh to downvote a new user with a well written question even if it is a duplicate!

Comment: I'd use `structure(colrs, names=tmp)`